# Awk - how to write cycle for more files

Tags: awk

I have a working script:

```
awk '
/^c/ { X[$2] = $3 }
/^c end/ { outfile = X["SatellID="] substr(X["ObsEndDa="],1,4) "." substr(X["SatFilte="],1,1)
           print "# Original file:", FILENAME, "satellite: " X["SatellID="], "observed: from", X["ObsStaDa="], "to", X["ObsStaDa="], "in", X["SatFilte="], "filter" > outfile }
!/^c/ { print $1, $2, $3 >> outfile }' file
```

I would like to write a cycle for more files in folder. What is wrong with this, please?

```
for file in *__final_flux_full.dat; do 
awk '
/^c/ { X[$2] = $3 }
/^c end/ { outfile = X["SatellID="] substr(X["ObsEndDa="],1,4) "." substr(X["SatFilte="],1,1)
           print "# Original file:", FILENAME, "satellite: " X["SatellID="], "observed: from", X["ObsStaDa="], "to", X["ObsStaDa="], "in", X["SatFilte="], "filter" > outfile }
!/^c/ { print $1, $2, $3 >> outfile }' ; done
```

There is no error. It is running and doing nothing. Thank you

Comment: You need to pass file variable to awk command so add like `"$file"` and it should fly then.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer too, but IMHO you could read this with `awk` itself; right now I fixed your code only, try running all files against `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix OP's code one could try:

```
for file in *__final_flux_full.dat; do 
awk '
/^c/ { X[$2] = $3 }
/^c end/ { outfile = X["SatellID="] substr(X["ObsEndDa="],1,4) "." substr(X["SatFilte="],1,1)
           print "# Original file:", FILENAME, "satellite: " X["SatellID="], "observed: from", X["ObsStaDa="], "to", X["ObsStaDa="], "in", X["SatFilte="], "filter" > outfile }
!/^c/ { print $1, $2, $3 >> outfile }' "$file" ; done
```

***In ideal scenario:*** Using an `awk` statement for each file is an OVERKILL, so you could pass all the files to your `awk` code too, also do add `close` statements for your output file to make you are NOT seeing `too many opened files` error.